# Seleccionar datos de una tabla y preguntar si no se encuentra en otra?

Tags: mysql, sql

Tengo esta consulta estoy tratando de capturar los datos de la tbl_proyecto y con el WHERER verificar que ese dato no se encuentre ya en la otra tabla. Pero no me esta tomando ningun valor

```
 function buscarClieProyec($idCliente){

    $clientes = DB::select('SELECT p.id,
                                   p.descripcion,
                                   p.id_cliente,
                                   p.fecha_contratacion,
                                   f.id_cliente
                            FROM tbl_proyecto p,
                            tbl_cliente_facturacion f
                            WHERE p.id_cliente = '.$idCliente.'
                            AND f.id_cliente != '.$idCliente.'');
    if(count($clientes) > 0){
      return $clientes;
    }else{
      return array();
    }
    }
```

Comment: Intenta con f.id_cliente <>

Comment: Si usas un `INNER JOIN` no te traerá los datos que no estén en la otra tabla, no hace falta un `WHERE` para eso.

Comment: La consulta sería simplemente: **`"SELECT p.id,
                                   p.descripcion,
                                   p.id_cliente,
                                   p.fecha_contratacion,
                                   f.id_cliente
                            FROM tbl_proyecto p
                           INNER JOIN tbl_cliente_facturacion f ON p.id_cliente=f.id_cliente
                            WHERE p.id_cliente = $idCliente";`**

Comment: ahora hace duplicados de los resultados

Comment: Si hace duplicados tienes que revisar los datos, puede que haya duplicados en ellos. Quizá tengas que normalizar los datos y establecer restricciones del tipo `UNIQUE` dependiendo del tipo de relación que haya entre las tablas.

Comment: No tienes los modelos creados? Con Eloquent sería muy fácil

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Usando LEFT JOIN y validando que cualquier columna NOT NULL del LEFT sea nula,
si existe, no será NULL.

```
SELECT p.*
  FROM tbl_proyecto p
    LEFT JOIN tbl_cliente_facturacion f
      ON f.id_cliente = p.id_cliente
  WHERE p.id_cliente = '.$idCliente.'
    AND f.id_cliente is null
```

Comment: Si me funciono gracias, aunque yo también tenia un error con lo que quería buscar pero

Answer (score 1):

Por tu intento y lo que preguntas, parece que estás buscando algo así:

```
SELECT p.id,
       p.descripcion,
       p.id_cliente,
       p.fecha_contratacion,
       f.id_cliente
FROM tbl_proyecto
  WHERE id_cliente NOT IN (
    SELECT DISTINCT id_cliente
      FROM tbl_cliente_facturacion
  );
```

Si estoy en lo cierto, no te ha funcionado porque en tu consulta estás haciendo un producto cartesiano que combina todos los elementos de una tabla con todos los de la otra. De ahí que no obtengas lo que esperas, y en cambio obtengas duplicados y cosas raras...

Con un `INNER JOIN` tampoco lo resolverías pues, por definición, un producto interno sólo te mostrará los elementos comunes de ambas tablas.

Para implementar esa resta, necesitarías un producto externo de tipo `LEFT JOIN`, el equivalente algo más eficiente que te he propuesto con `NOT IN`.

Déjame en los comentarios cualquier cuestión para poder ampliar la respuesta lo mejor posible.

Comment: Si era la idea que queriaa aunque termine usando el Left Join y yo tenia una pequeña equivocacion con lo que queria comparar pero era la idea al final quedo asi.          SELECT p.*
                            FROM tbl_proyecto p
                            LEFT JOIN tbl_cliente_facturacion f
                              ON f.id_proyecto = p.id
                            WHERE p.id_cliente = '.$idCliente.'
                              AND f.id_proyecto is not null

Comment: Efectivamente, son equivalentes. Siempre he preferido el `LEFT JOIN`, aunque últimamente uso más el `NOT IN` porque reduce el tiempo de ejecución